# Ferramentas comuns entre programadores podem ser perguntas on-topic?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

No "escopo" do site temos o seguinte:

- um problema específico de programação
- um algorítimo de software
- **ferramentas comuns entre programadores**
- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Este trecho **ferramentas comuns entre programadores** da a entender que a pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78809/para-que-serve-o-sublime-text é on-topic (o autor deletou já):

> ## Para que serve o Sublime Text
>
> Gostaria de saber para qual melhor finalidade o Sublime Text pode trazer para o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo?

Eu solicitei fechar como off-topic, mas pensei também em fechar como "baseada em opiniões".

No entanto fiquei na duvida, sobre como é o escopo do site sobre ferramentas comuns entre programadores, como isto se encaixa no escopo do que pode ser perguntado?

Comment: Muito ampla também imho...

Comment: Não acho que seja muito amplo nem baseado em opiniões

Comment: Não havia lido o corpo da pergunta, somente o título. A palavra "melhor" é algo que quase sempre leva ao fechamento, por mim, essa pergunta está quase no tópico, não faltava muito para estar dentro dele.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/101 o problema nem é a palavra melhor, embora ela só faz o texto ficar confuso. Convenhamos, mal dá para entender o que está escrito ali. A única resposta que consigo dar ali é que ele ajuda escrever códigos como qualquer outro editor de texto voltado p/ programadores ou um IDE. A pergunta sequer faz sentido. Eu ia até tentar ver se ele queria saber alguma coisa específica mas removeu e nesses casos a pessoa não sabe o que quer, só queria postar. Do jeito que estava cada um iria dizer o que bem entende, divulgar o que acha bom nele e nada útil sairia dali

Comment: É engraçado esse tipo de pergunta, na qual o título não está relacionado com o que é perguntado. **Título:** *O que é StackOverflow?* **Conteúdo**: *Olá, gostaria de saber como o StackOverflow pode me ajudar a temperar um bife*. Enfim, nesse caso eu achei a pergunta ampla demais, não por conta de questionar a melhor finalidade do editor (embora isso também seja complicado de responder), mas torná-la subjetiva em não dar maiores detalhes do aplicativo que ele quer desenvolver. "Sublime Text" e "aplicativo" na mesma frase só me faz pensar em Ionic, Cordova e Phonegapp, mas... quem garante?!

Comment: @re22 eu acho que ele deve estar discutindo com alguém sobre o uso do sublimetext na empresa por exemplo e queria ter argumentos para discutir com outra pessoa.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta em questão está bem "resolvida", mas esta pergunta aqui do Meta é que está estranha. Se o problema da pergunta (sobre Sublime Text) é como foi perguntada, porque a pergunta é sobre o escopo aceitável (que, em princípio, está decidido)? O objetivo era discutir esta pergunta específica, ou abrir a discussão sobre perguntas (bem feitas) sobre ferramentas?

Comment: @Molx quando é sobre a pergunta especifica usamos a tag `pergunta-especifica` e como o autor deletou a questão não há o que discutir sobre isto, neste caso não é sobre a pergunta, ela é um exemplo. Pelos comentários anteriores foi  possível se notar que a pergunta estava mal formada e apenas isto. A pergunta **é**: *No entanto fiquei na duvida, sobre como é o escopo do site sobre ferramentas comuns entre programadores, como isto se encaixa no escopo do que pode ser perguntado?*

Comment: acho que esse tipo de pergunta é do tipo "caça medalha"..  Acho que se fosse algo mais específico como o que o Guilherme comentou ( argumentando dentro de uma empresa.. ) a questão seria algo como "qual a vantagem ou desvantagem" "qual o benefício de uso.." . Acho que seria por aí, mas da forma como está, do meu ponto de vista está mais para caça medalhas.   Por mim, tudo bem querer caçar medalha, mas desde que a questão tenha um nível de qualidade um pouco melhor que aquilo.